# PHP Play sound if a variable is over a number

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'd like to know how could I play a sound if my variable is bigger than another, or bigger than a number.

I also need the sound to be compatible with Internet Explorer, and the box to be invisible.

I've tried lots of things but came to nothing. So I am asking for your help.

Comment: Any code is appreciated! :P

Comment: You better use soundmanager.js to play sound. And download the condition from PHP using Ajax on an interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your equation results with true, echo out an html5 audio tag and make it autoplay. Something like

```
<audio controls autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none">
<source src="example.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: That works on Firefox or Chrome,but I need it for Internet Explorer,and I need it to be invisible...Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: The [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp) page says it is supported by IE. Try style="display:none" in the audio tag. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried to display:none,but then,sound doesn't play...
On IE,it doesn't even play,it doesn't even show..

Comment: Guys,IE doesn't play it,and I really really need it only for IE... :(

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?
Possible options:
    <object height="50" width="100" data="horse.mp3"></object>


Or
     <embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3"  autostart="true">

Comment: I am using Version 8. Thank you for your reply,but none of these work on IE :(

Comment: Yet another possibility: <bgsound id="background_snd" src="static/audio/clip.mp3" autostart="true" loop="1">

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Javascript library I use, which is named [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org), it's a plugin for the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) Javascript library.

You can build something with your PHP script to write this little piece of Javascript code in your page :

```
$(function() {
  $("#audio").jPlayer({ // Selector, in this case the player in not shown
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: 'hellmarch.mp3'
      }).jPlayer('play'); // Play immediately
    },
    supplied: 'mp3',
    swfPath: ''
  });
});
```

This code will immediately play the audio file named `hellmarch.mp3`.